# How to run uniCenta POS (Version 3.91.3) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I successfully installed uniCenta POS in 2 PCs: one with Ubuntu 15.10, and the other with Ubuntu 16.04, both with Spanish (Español) installations
(I downloaded and executed the installation with: unicentaopos-3.91.3-linux-x64-installer.run).
The program runs normally through the terminal with: sudo ./start.sh

Now I try to make a Desktop entry for the application:
I created a file called: Unicenta.desktop, located in: /usr/share/applications, with the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Unicenta 
Comment=Fires up Unicenta oPOS 
Type=Application 
Exec=/home/barmistias/unicentaopos-3.91.3/start.sh 
Icon=/home/barmistias/unicentaopos-3.91.3/unicentaopos.ico 
Terminal=false
```

At this stage, it doesn't create any icon & launcher (but it already should, right?)

The locations for the executable start.sh and the icon file are correct. Now, through the terminal, I try to turn the files into executables:
when I'm located in the folder: /usr/share/applications:

```
sudo chmod 775 ./Unicenta.desktop  with ls -l I get: -rwxrwxr-x
```

and when I'm located in the folder: /home/barmistias/unicentaopos-3.91.3:

```
sudo chmod 775 ./start.sh  with ls -l I get: -rwxrwxr-x
sudo chmod 777 ./unicentaopos.jar with ls -l I get: -rwxrwxrwx
```

Additionally, I put the right path in the start.sh file:

## start uniCenta oPOS

```
java -cp $CP -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel -jar /home/barmistias/unicentaopos-3.91.3/unicentaopos.jar "$@"
```

So, it should work, but it doesn't. Additionally, if I turn the start.sh into executable by activating in properties: “Allow executing file as program”, the application launches differently (with the derby database deactivated, and unable to save a change to this setting. It only loops with the settings window, so it doesn't allow to get to the main window of the program).

So, in conclusion, how do I create a desktop icon that successfully and normally launches uniCenta POS (Version 3.91.3)?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

How do I create a desktop icon that successfully and normally launches uniCenta POS (Version 3.91.3)

Try this:

- Create Unicenta.desktop in your Desktop directory (`/home/barmistias/Desktop`), just like you did above.
- Change `start.sh` to `launcher.sh` from the `Exec=` line.
- Create the file `launcher.sh` like so;

  ```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd /home/barmistias/unicentaopos-3.91.3/

    ./start.sh
  ```
- Set execute permission for `launcher.sh` and `Unicenta.desktop`
- Now test.

The guide was taken from [this blog post](http://chubbable.com/unicenta-3-9-ubuntu-16-install-guide)

Also, searching for `unicenta desktop shortcut not working solution` yields helpful articles from Unicenta discussion pages and other blog posts.